# Application freezes just after goin back from desktop to app (on android device)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, lag, resume

It tooks a lot of time to unfreeze (but sometimes it just crashes).

I was debugging whole code to find a place where the problem is and I found that there's something wrong while I was saving things to Player Prefs.

My "idea" why it is causing. Multiple times getting and setting prefs with different values.

Test code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Image bg;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text text;

    //private void Start()
    //{
    //    PlayerPrefs.SetString("dd", "x");
    //}
    //Update is called once per frame

    //bool was = false;
    int counter = 0;
    System.DateTime lastUpdate;
    bool active = false;
    List<string> tmp = new List<string>() { "5", "7" };

    private void Start()
    {
        lastUpdate = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
        System.TimeSpan diff = now - lastUpdate;
        text.text = diff.ToString();
        if (diff.TotalSeconds > 10)
        {
            active = !active;
            lastUpdate = now;
        }

        if (active)
        {
            bg.color = Color.green;
            //if ((System.DateTime.UtcNow - xyz).TotalSeconds > 5)
            //if (counter > 5)
            //{
            //if (!was)
            //{
            //    Debug.Log("XX_update");
            //}

            //was = true;
            //string x = PlayerPrefs.GetString("dd");
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                string x = PlayerPrefs.GetString("dd");
                Set(5, i);
                //string x = PlayerPrefs.GetString(CommonMethods.RandomString(5));
            }
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    was = false;
            //    counter++;
            //}
        }
        else
        {
            bg.color = Color.red;
        }
    }

    private System.DateTime xyz = System.DateTime.UtcNow;

    public void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
    {
        counter = 0;
        Debug.Log("XX_onappfocus");

        xyz = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
    }


    public void Set(double value, int x = 0)
    {
        //PlayerPrefs.SetString(name, value.ToString("E3"));
        //string costam = random.NextDouble().ToString();
        //PlayerPrefs.SetString(name, costam);
        //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("XX_" + costam);

        //List<string> tmp = new List<string>() { "98754.38238715351", "98754.38238415351" };
        //string result = tmp.RandomElement();
        string result = tmp[x % 2];
        //PlayerPrefs.SetString(name, result);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("dd", result);
        //PlayerPrefs.SetString(name, "1.054E+003");
    }
}
```

I was thinking that maybe there's a problem with double's precision, but it wasn't. Then I checked if it is caused by parsing inside setstring methods, but it wasn't. Problem isn't connected with a key, so it can be random.

If you want to check this try to build this code with 2 different values in tmp string list (now it's 5 and 7) and there will be bug, then change these values to the same (f.e. 5 and 5). Problem will disappear. Also you can delete get or set from FOR loop and problem will also disappear.

I also made a tricky switch inside Update method to check if it is connected with this get / set pair so you can check it too.

Sorry for my english guys but this problem is so complex that I even don't know how to describe it. I am trying to solve it for 3 days (we need to solve this or make a 'walk around' because we can't use that app without this).

Thanks in advance.